# Model performance on test set fluctuates highly from epoch to epoch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have been trying to learn a binary classifier for photos with the following arhitechture:

```
class PatchNDepthBasedCNN:

    @staticmethod
    def build(width=256, height=256, depth=3):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # "channels last" and the channels dimension itself
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1

        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1

        # 1
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same"))

        # 2
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        x1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same")
        model.add(x1)
        # the reshaped tensor will be used later in concatenate
        print(x1.output.shape)
        x1r = Reshape((int(width / 8), int(height / 8), 128))(x1.output)

        # 3
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        x2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same")
        model.add(x2)

        # 4
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        x3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same")
        model.add(x3)
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # 5 - concat
        c = Concatenate()([x1r, x2.output, x3.output])
        model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=c))

        # 6 -
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # 7
        final_layer = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same")
        model.add(final_layer)
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))


        # * first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(64))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        # model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        # softmax classifier
        model.add(Dense(2))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        return model

        

new_model = PatchNDepthBasedCNN.build(width=IMG_DIM, height=IMG_DIM, depth=3)
new_model.compile(
    optimizer="rmsprop",
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

During training, I save the model at each epoch (for the purpose of experiment). I always thought that the latest model (the latest epoch) must be the preferred one (in case the model hasn't started to overfit). Still, when I assess each variant (epoch) of the trained model on the test set (from another data distribution), I get randomly fluctuating results from epoch to epoch. Say, the test accuracy on epoch 60 can be around 72%, epoch 61 - 97%, epoch 63 - 80%.

At the same time, if I substitute the last two layers of the model, and change the loss function to simulate SVM, I get overall worse results, but the tendency is clearly seen from epoch to epoch (test accuracy slowly rises from base 50% to around 78%, and then fluctuates within a small margin):

```
class PatchNDepthBasedCNN:

    @staticmethod
    def build(width=256, height=256, depth=3):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # "channels last" and the channels dimension itself
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1

        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1

        # 1
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same"))

        # 2
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        x1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same")
        model.add(x1)
        # the reshaped tensor will be used later in concatenate
        print(x1.output.shape)
        x1r = Reshape((int(width / 8), int(height / 8), 128))(x1.output)

        # 3
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        x2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same")
        model.add(x2)

        # 4
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        x3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same")
        model.add(x3)
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # 5 - concat
        c = Concatenate()([x1r, x2.output, x3.output])
        model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=c))

        # 6 -
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # 7
        final_layer = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same")
        model.add(final_layer)
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))


        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Dense(2, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001)))
        model.add(Activation('linear'))

        return model

        

new_model = PatchNDepthBasedCNN.build(width=IMG_DIM, height=IMG_DIM, depth=3)
new_model.compile(loss='hinge',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

1. What are the possble reasons/explanations for this behavior?
2. What advice could you give me to try achieve better results (if it is possible to infer from the provided data)?

Thank you for considering my question!

**EDIT**: Removed unused code (LR and other unused parameters from the model, they weren't actually taken into account while training the model, just forgot to remove them)

Comment: Fluctuating metrics could be a sign of the learning rate being too high, as the resulting adjustment during the weight update step is causing a ping-pong effect on the loss (if you imagine a simple U-curve gaph). Try setting your optimiser to `tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(0.0001)` (the default is 0.001)

Comment: Also it looks like your `LR` parameter isn't being used, as you're using the 'automatic' optimiser by just having the string `adadelta` instead of using the path to the actual optimiser

Comment: @ML_Engine, thanks for your response! The fluctuating pattern was observed when training with the 'rmsprop' optimizer (please, see the end of the first code block), not with the Adadelta optimizer. Maybe, I should try use adadelta with instead of rmsprop in the first code block?

Comment: Ah I see, I think in any case, whichever optimiser you are using, grab the original path to the optimiser in tf-keras, have a look at the docs to see what the default is, and just add an extra zero and keep doing that until the training stabilises.

Comment: @ML_Engine, I didn't quite get what you mean... The training process goes well, with gradual decrease of loss and increase of accuracy with the both variants, the problems are with the test set (not with the validation set during training). The training set accuracy approaches 99% (both training and validation data). The problem is the model generalization behavior (that is, predicting data for new samples from another data distribution) is strange.

Comment: To add to @ML_Engine, along with reducing learning rate and selecting different optimizer like Adam and you can also try shuffling the data which will distribute your data properly and try reducing the batch size and in the loss curve observe the loss fluctuation from each batch.
If it doesn't improve then reduce the learning rate even smaller,else you can also explore on learning rate with momentum to take smaller steps near global optimum.

Comment: @Tfer3, thank you for the help, will try what you have suggested